# Is this symbol equivalent to taking a partial derivative?

Tags: notation, partial-derivative

On the Wikipedia page for the Leibniz Rule for Integration, it displays this formula:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int f(x,t)\,dt = \int\partial_xf(x,t)\,dt
$$

Is the symbol $\partial_x$ equivalent to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}?$ If so, is this just a preference of convention? If I use this symbol, will people get confused?

Comment: In my experience, that notation is standard. If I saw $\partial_x$ in this context I would not be confused

Comment: Yes it is completely normal to use that symbol, it shows up all the time, and is a very convenient quickhand, especially if I don't want to define variables. For example, if I just have a function $f$ with $7$ inputs, I don't have to go through the trouble of defining variables anymore, I can just say $\partial_6 f$ to denote the derivative w.r.t. to input $6$. This is useful especially if some one pulls a trick question on you such as, what is $\partial_x f(y,x)$ for a function $f(x,y)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\partial_xf(\cdot)$ and $\frac\partial{\partial x}f(\cdot)$ denote completely the same thing, and nobody will be confused. The former way is just a more concise formulation.